# grails table for domain with byte[] is not created with H2

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I'm trying to store domain with bytes[] and using H2 database. But for some reason table for the domain class is not created automatically, my domain structure is as follows:

```
class Image {
    String imageUID
    byte[] imageBlob


    static constraints = {
        imageUID nullable: false
        imageBlob maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2
    }

    static mapping = {
        imageUID column: "image_uid", defaultValue: "non-unique"
    }

}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I removed `imageUID column: "image_uid", defaultValue: "non-unique"` and table was created